# Raising an event on a control in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, command

I am trying to write a XAML control for a Piano Keyboard in WPF which responds to NoteOn and NoteOff MIDI events from an external MIDI keyboard.  I am using Tom Lokovic's midi-dot-net to raise NoteOn and NoteOff events triggered by the hardware but I need a way to get these events to raise the NoteOn and NoteOff events of my XAML Key class (derived from the WPF Button).  The colour of a key should change when it is on and the event should be subscribable to so that a user of the Piano Keyboard control can play a sound the key is pressed.

I could do this by passing every Midi.InputDevice to every single key on the keyboard so that each one can subscribe to the NoteOn and NoteOff events of every InputDevice then, in turn raise their own NoteOn and NoteOff events but the problem with this is that the PianoKeyboard control (an ItemsControl which holds Keys) and its nested Key controls all become tightly coupled to the implementation of midi-dot-net.  If I have to do this I will, but it seemed like there should be a better way of doing this in WPF moving the dependency on midi-dot-net higher up in the call stack.

I have too much code to paste in its entirety here and still be readable so here's a sample of one of the DataTemplates I'm using as my PianoKeyboard's ItemTemplate.

`<DataTemplate x:Key="naturalKeyTemplate">
    <!--NOTE: Background and Foreground Color assignment and changing is accounted for in the style.-->
    <local:Key Grid.Column="{Binding Converter={StaticResource keyToColumnNumberConverter}}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Converter={StaticResource keyToColumnSpanConverter}}"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Style="{StaticResource naturalKeyStyle}"
        Note="{Binding Note}"
        IsHighlighted="{Binding IsHighlighted}">
<!--TODO: Find a way of raising the Key's NoteOn and NoteOff events from here.-->
    </local:Key>
</DataTemplate>`

Essentially what I'm asking is: given an input device is not supported to trigger a WPF button with the button's built in behaviour (e.g. a mouse click), how does one get it to trigger the button without coupling it to a derived class of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could raise the `Click` event programmatically:

```
button1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid putting the logic in the code-behind so I don't have to set the DataContext of the PianoKeyboard control to itself (although currently it is for other reasons which I'm trying to eliminate also).  If I depend on bindings to the code behind then all it takes is a user of the control to set its data context to something else and it will break if they don't know what should be on their DataContext to support it.

Comment: This code doesn't go in the code-behind of the view, it goes in the custom control class.

Comment: The PianoKeyboard control class?

Comment: I guess. Whenever you get an MIDI library event, you programmatically raise the WPF event.

Comment: Hmm, if it was in the PianoKeyboard class then it would have to look at the PianoKeyboard's Items to find the Key to raise the NoteOn event for (if there was one).  I can see how it would work but is this the proper (MVVM) way to do it in WPF?

Comment: This functionality certainly belongs to the view or the control. It is certainly not the responsibility of the view model to raise routed events.

Comment: So am I right in thinking the code-behind the PianoKeyboard is not considered the view model if it is not the DataContext of the control?

Comment: PianoKeyboard  is a control, isn't it? Then it cannot be a view model.

Comment: The PianoKeyboard is a control.  Isn't the view model is what is bound to by the view / control's XAML?

Comment: Yes. But how is this related to your original question? If you have any questions about MVVM you should ask a new question.

Comment: I wish to put the code to raise the event in a place which does not break MVVM, hence "Raising an event on a control in XAML".

Comment: As I have already told you, this place is either in the view or in the control.

Comment: Ok, based on your solution I was able to derive this for the event handler to the MIDI NoteOn event.
```private void InputDevice_NoteOn(NoteOnMessage msg)
  {
   foreach (Key pressedKey in Items.OfType<Key>().Where(key => new Models.MusicalConstructs.Notes.Note(msg.Pitch).Equals(key.Note)))
    pressedKey.RaiseEvent(new NoteEventArgs(pressedKey.Note, Key.NoteOnEvent));
  }```
Using the `OfType<Key>` filter on Items should prevent it from breaking the PianoKeyboard control if someone decides to abuse the PianoKeyboard by putting things other than keys in it.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you to call specific Metod based on event called.

```
<local:Key>  
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Mouse.PreviewMouseDown">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="NoteOn"
                                     TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Mouse.PreviewMouseUp">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="NoteOff"
                                     TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
     </local:Key>
```

You will need to add xmlns extensions:

```
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
 xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Comment: I think this could be what I'm after; so would I be correct in thinking that NoteOn would be a method on my Binding object and, when called, it will fire Mouse.PreviewMouseDown on my Key control?

Comment: Actually its oposite, Mouse.PreviewMouseDown will call method NoteOn.

Comment: Oh hang on, that's the opposite way around!  I need the NoteOn and NoteOff events on Key (or MouseUp and MouseDown instead, if possible) to be fired by the NoteOn and NoteOff events of the MIDI library I'm using.

Comment: then maybe as @mm8 said to raise click programatically in code behinde.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done a MIDI listenner service singleton that listen to all midi events, which update a keyboard state repository, which expose a viewmodel binded to your keyboard control...but i do not really see your programm structure, so it's not easy to say.

binding the midi event in your xaml to the wrapper midi.net does not seems to be the LOB way, because you link the gui with midi.net...

by the way, On/Off, is not enough, you need "pressed" as key is pressed state??

Comment: "On" would be the pressed state but I noticed the IsPressed property on ButtonBase is read-only so unfortunately I cannot use that to trigger the button.

Comment: Regarding the MIDI NoteOn and NoteOff events, my question would be how do Microsoft do it with the Mouse events that come from the hardware?  Would they use a singleton?  I thought singletons were bad practice as they introduce global state.

Comment: if your keyboard is mvvm binded, then isPressed would work...I do not catch it right ? do you want to fire an event or get the one from midi.net ?

Comment: I'm using an event from MIDI.NET to fire another event by the same name on my Key class.  Which instance of the Key class needs its NoteOn or NoteOff event firing depends on which note is pressed.  I think mm8's solution will do the trick but I'd be interested to know if there a way to do it in XAML.

Comment: are you MVVM ? why do you want to fire an business event from the key control ? what are you going to do with it ?

Comment: I'm trying to keep things MVVM but ultimately I would be firing a business event from the key control (at the moment indirectly through the PianoKeyboard control but I hope to move this higher up the stack going forward).  Isn't this what happens when a Mouse Click is received from the mouse hardware interface when over a given button though?

The NoteOn event on the Key control would be subscribed to as attached property on the PianoKeyboard which a user of the PianoKeyboard could then play an appropriate sound from their event handler.  Also, I want keys to light up as they are pressed.

Comment: search for samples : https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WPFKeyboard or https://www.codeproject.com/script/articles/articleversion.aspx?aid=480946&av=690563